# Can mongosh (new MongoDB shell) produce the same output format than mongo (legacy MongoDB shell)?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongosh

The following command executed with legacy `mongo` shell:

```
mongo --quiet << EOF
  show dbs
EOF
```

provides this output

```
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

However, the same command with new shell (`mongosh`)

```
$ mongosh --quiet << EOF
  show dbs
EOF
```

provides a slightly different ouput:

```
test>   show dbs
admin   40.00 KiB
config  36.00 KiB
local   40.00 KiB
test>
```

I have a set of old script using `mongo` that I want to migrate to `mongosh` but that slight difference in the output makes them break in some point. I wonder if I could avoid extra work adapting it configuring `mongosh` to provide output in the exact same way than `mongo`.

Is there some way of doing so, please?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** the `show db` above is just an example. I'm looking for a general solution that covers in general any other case. For instance, this new one:

Legacy shell:

```
$ echo 'db.dropDatabase()' | mongo sample-db --quiet
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

New shell:

```
$ echo 'db.dropDatabase()' | mongosh sample-db --quiet
sample-db> db.dropDatabase()
{ ok: 1, dropped: 'sample-db' }
sample-db>
```

In fact, just the ability of removing the prompt part that output (`test>`, `sample-db>`, etc.) would help a lot.

Comment: For **every** command I don't think it is possible. The prompt you can customize by `prompt = function() { return 'my prompt> '};`

Comment: Please have a look at my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [eval](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/options/#std-option-mongosh.--eval) parameter for that.

Instead of

```
$ echo 'db.dropDatabase()' | mongosh sample-db --quiet
```

Do

```
$ mongosh sample-db --quiet --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'
```

It outputs exactly

```
{ ok: 1, dropped: 'sample-db' }
```

Answer (score 1):

`show dbs` is a shell internal command, thus it would be difficult.

Some commands from legacy mongo shell you can get by loading [mongocompat](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongosh-snippets/tree/main/snippets/mongocompat). You can add this to your `.mongoshrc.js`

```
load('.../index.js');
```

To get all databases you can also query collection `db.getSiblingDB('config').databases`

Try

```
db.getSiblingDB('config').databases.find({}).forEach(x => {
   print(`${x._id} ${db.getSiblingDB(x._id).stats(1000 * 1000 * 1000).storageSize}GB`)
})
```

It should produce the same output as `show dbs`

For your problem, better use

```
mongosh --quiet --nodb --eval 'print("Hello World")'
Hello World
```

instead of

```
echo 'print("Hello World")' | mongosh --quiet --nodb 
(NoDB)> print("Hello World")
Hello World

(NoDB)>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! `show dbs` was only an example, I have edited the question to explain that. Sorry for not doing so in my first post...